# HAML Error (New to Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a HAML file that is creating an error:

```
%li#guest_dropdown.dropdown.inverse-dropdown.active
  = link_to 'Guest/Sign In', '#', class: 'dropdown-toggle',
            'data-toggle' => 'dropdown', role: :button, 'aria-expanded' => :false, id: :user_name
  %ul.dropdown-menu{role: :menu}
  %li#user_checkout= link_to 'Shopping Cart', users_checkout_path
    %li.divider{role: :presentation}
    %li#user_dropdown_sign_out= link_to 'Sign In', user_session_path
```

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful to include the error text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your 5th line, that `li` should be nested inside the `ul`